# Best way to save html5 canvas data as object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on an html5 canvas application that you can construct a room with it, which has some tools that are draggable such as room furniture that are extracted from the database.

now I know that I can save the canvas to a png image using:

```
  // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

But I want to save the representation of the canvas not how it looks!  Like an object or something, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: If by save as object, you mean have the necessary information to reconstruct the image, will need to create the object as you create the canvas.

Comment: take a look to the source of a framework like http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: In the DOM everything is a node. We use functions(methods) on an element eq. element.addEventListner() since thy are all objects. As @AlexanderO'Mara said that you could have necesary info to reconstruct use the clone method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use JSON to save/restore your room**

1. Create a room array that holds all the furniture objects contained in that room:

   ```
   var room=[];

   room.push({x:20,y:150,furniture:'couch'});
   room.push({x:30,y:250,furniture:'table'});
   room.push({x:40,y:350,furniture:'chair'});
   ```
2. Then you can save that array of furniture objects to a string using JSON.stringify.

   ```
   var roomAsString=JSON.stringify(room);
   ```
3. Now that your room is stored as a string, you can save it to your database (maybe using AJAX).
4. When needed, retrieve the string from your database (maybe using AJAX).
5. After you retrieve the string, you can use it to recreate the room array using JSON.parse.

   ```
   var room=JSON.parse(roomAsString);
   ```

And finally redraw the room based on the furniture objects in the room array.

Comment: so i have to manually build everything by myself , and there is not representation for the canvas itself ?

Comment: Yes...No...You are the programmer after all ;-)